# How do I change user account used by the Update tab of AppStore?

Tags: ios-appstore

On the bottom of the Featured tab Apple ID is correct, but when I try to update an app App Store asks me a password for the old Apple ID that I no longer have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you downloaded some app using that old ID. When the app downloaded using that ID tries to update, it asks for the password of that ID.

Answer (score 2):

You bought the apps with your old Apple ID. Apps are permanently tied to the ID with which they were bought.

I'm fairly certain if you deleted them, and re-downloaded them with your new ID, the problem would be solved. You would, however, have to pay for them again if they were not free.

Relevant questions:

[Attempting to update app asks for a different iTunes account password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117814/attempting-to-update-app-asks-for-a-different-itunes-account-password?rq=1) (pretty much a duplicate)

[How can I find which account I used for downloading my iOS apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/how-can-i-find-which-account-i-used-for-downloading-my-ios-apps?rq=1)